# MySQL - See if a radius intersects a polygon

Tags: mysql, google-maps, polygon

I have a table of "areas" and with the table I have a field called polygon that defines that area.  Here is an example of the data in the polygon

`(51.562537549259275, -0.18651649218749844),(51.56518165749251, -0.1497333723210481),(51.55111270638887, -0.10924630850248862),(51.568708395618486, -0.12155901469758534),(51.51636175962405, -0.07797281013359303),(51.46339366897244, -0.1081939612190741),(51.45202948056895, -0.13394078643432783),(51.44657087249458, -0.14909693896627108),(51.43333085349518, -0.18476873548843198),(51.42143028245271, -0.16866370898437344),(51.42048689213698, -0.2246564608006274),(51.410609105933894, -0.2541484477524758),(51.38180048734274, -0.31050333075316905),(51.38632646897756, -0.3486097751090478),(51.4462317250533, -0.39531041838200887),(51.482412594272446, -0.33524472163053654),(51.49386310130167, -0.31459844345063326),(51.57115695855739, -0.25625859642894877),`

This polygon is created in Google Maps, if changing this data to something different would help, I can do that, I'm not stuck with this data format.

In the front end the client does a search by picking a location (which gives the latitude and longitude) and a radius to search.

Is there a way in MySQL to see if these 2 things intersect?  Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: your question is very vague, we need more info on your problem. please provide the SQL scripts to create your table(s) and insert data into them as well as the query you have developed so far (even if the query doesn't give you what you want right now)

Comment: this looks like you have a lot of points (langitude , longitude) and no polygon.  a polygon would wlook like this SET @g = 'POLYGON((22.367582117085913 70.71181669186944, 22.225161442616514 70.65582486840117, 22.20736264867434 70.83229276390898, 22.18701840565626 70.9867880031668, 22.22452581029355 71.0918447658621, 22.382709129816103 70.98884793969023, 22.40112042636022 70.94078275414336, 22.411912121843205 70.7849142238699, 22.367582117085913 70.71181669186944))';

Comment: @Mike I'm sorry you were downvoted, I was not responsible for the downvote however. It is generally considered impolite to make false accusations, try not to be rude to those trying to help you. As far as my original comment about the question being vague, please see these 2 help items that talk about how to ask a question properly and providing a minimum reproduceable SQL query: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   
     ||          https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak  Apologies for my rant, I was annoyed that I could no longer make comments on questions that didn't require a full on answer.  I will try to give more details when I post a question again but I do think there was enough there, I had no SQL to give ..... although actually I had played around a little with things that turned out to be the actual answer, so, you could be right.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who has this issue, I found the solution.

As mentioned in the initial post, I had a field called polygon that held the polygon in the format also shown.  I created a new field called enc_polygon of type POLYGON and wrote PHP to convert polygon to enc_polygon on insert and update.  I won't show this as people are unlikely to be saving in the same format as I was using!

One thing worth mentioning is that for a POLYGON database field to work, the first and last coordinates have to be the same, to close it, for Google maps, it doesn't.

Now I have the polygon in the database I can do this

```
SELECT *
FROM   AREAS
WHERE ......
AND   ST_Within(ST_PointFromText('POINT($latitude $longitude)'), ST_Buffer(enc_polygon, 0.008983157 * $distance )) = 1
```

The latitude and longitude aren't from the database, so I need to convert them to a Point, this is using [ST_PointFromText](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_pointfromtext/).

The distance is also entered on the page as how far the user is willing to travel in kilometres.  So I used the [ST_Buffer](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_buffer/)  function to put a buffer of the entered distance around the whole polygon.

[ST_Within](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st-within/) is pretty obvious I think, but it basically returns 1 if the point is within the buffered polygon.